# CSS and control name mangling in content pages

Tags: asp.net, master-pages, name-mangling

I have a simple website with a master-page. To set properties to elements on a content page (such as `Textbox`) I use CSS. In designer it works well but when I launch a site a style isn't apllied to controls. The reason is simple. To say, I have a `TextBox` with `id="TextBox1"` in content page, it is placed in `ContentPlaceHolder1`. In CSS file I set properties for object with id `#TextBox1`. When I launch a site due to master page name mangling it gets an id like `ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_TextBox1` which is not defined in CSS file included in masterpage.

What is a correct solution of this problem? Hardcoding mangled name doesn't seem to be good.

Comment: make the effort of creating true CASCADING style sheet files because that what that word is in the acronym for. It sounds like you might be relying too much on ID selectors there. Use classes more and use tag selectors more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `CssClass` on the controls, like this:  `CssClass="myClass"`, then in your stylesheet instead of this:

```
#TextBox1 { /* styles */ }
```

You'd have this:

```
.myClass { /* styles */ }
```

It's worth noting that .Net 4 fixes, or allows you to better manage the ID generated in the html, [see here for details](http://weblogs.asp.net/asptest/archive/2009/01/06/asp-net-4-0-clientid-overview.aspx).

Comment: It's obvious but I already use classes for them. For some controls I use classes to set common properties (such as width and height) and ids for individual (for example, background). So in your solution I'll have to lot's of copy-paste to put properties from common class to new classes made instead of their ids.

Comment: @flashnik - Not so! You can do this: `CssClass="class1 class2 class3"` just use a space between to assign multiple classes.  If the classes have the same property defined, the last one in the list wins.

Comment: Thank you, now it's clear. I haven't known I can write several classes in `class=`.

Comment: @flashnik - I didn't either for the longest time, very handy eh? :)

Answer (score 2):

As Nick and SLaks have both said classes are best.  You can assign multiple classes in the class property and it will aggregate all the properties from all the classes specified overwrite any of the properties that it shares with earlier classes.  The order of the classes definition in the css file sets the order that they get applied.

```
<style type="text/css">
.genericTextBox
{
background-color: #eee;
color: black;
}
.textbox1
{
background-color: #3ee;
font-size: larger;
}
</style>

<asp:TextBox id="textBox1" CssClass="textbox1 genericTextBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

The order the styles get applied is first genericTextBox, because its the first defined in the style (essentially the order in class gets ignored).  It sets the color and the background-color, then the style textbox1 gets applied and it overwrites the background-color and adds font-size to.  So in the end you end with the color from generictextbox, the background-color and font-size from textbox1.

EDIT:  on the TextBox changed class to CssClass

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to apply your CSS rules using classnames (Which don't get mangled) instead of IDs.

<strike>The correct solution is to use the [`ClientID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid.aspx) property, which returns the mangled ID.</strike>

For example:

```
.Something #<%=TextBox1.ClientID %>` {
    color: red;
}
```

However, you can only do that for inline stylesheets.

Comment: What should I add so that using symbols like `<%=` wouldn't be an error? VS shows that there is no selector.

Comment: VS will show a syntax error; that's a bug in the editor.  If you run the page, it _will_ work.  (Only if the CSS is inline)

Comment: No, it wasn't inline, it's in a separate file.